# How to change ActionBar color?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

How could I change ActionBar color?
I've implemeted this and it works but not as I want. it changes color only after activity started, so right after app launch the original bar colour is showed, and only a second later my custom color is dislpayed. Is there any other way to handle that?
Thanks in advance

```
....
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    ActionBar actionBar;
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#879f38")));
.....
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Eclipse throws an error `no resource found that matches the given name Widget.Holo.ActionBar ` What is wrong here?

Comment: @AvanJogia Oh sorry I left something out. I edited my answer. Check it out now.

Comment: In the same way, how can I change the action bar tab's underbar color to something different color instead of the default blue.

Comment: @Ahmad hello sir..plz help me..i try this code but my app unfortunately stop..what i do????plz help me..