# Why my app is errors when I just create it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use android studio with sdk v24.
When I create my new application and just go to the MainActivity.jar It shows me many codes red?
Here it is that I'm talking about:(screen shot)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100174344/Screenshot%202015-01-06%2008.06.09.png

I'm really confused. How can I fix these errors?

NOTE: my sdk is up to date (as you see here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100174344/Screenshot%202015-01-06%2008.22.28.png )
and I've added this code to my build.gradle(Module: app) :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' }
```

**EDIT:**
I'm sorry I create a new project and still it show me the codes, red but I can run it in AVD. what's the problem?

Comment: Download support repository from sdk manager and sync your project with gradle.

Comment: My sdk is up to date. but stil it is crashing.

Comment: While syncing what error message console is showubg you ?

Comment: No error is showing. but if I open my app in any AVD it crashes.

Comment: What crash log says ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want To add android.support.v7.jar not added that y  i think this error occurs.

add this in your project property file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```

Comment: maybe. but when I write the import code manually I can write it up to here: "import import android.support.v7" but after that, it's going to crash

Comment: no first you orgnize import in studio.
and then You can not see the v7 jar classes.
measns it can not reference to your v7.jar

Answer (score 0):

Did you added  android.support.v7.jar? Just make sure your sdk is updated and you've added  android.support.v7.jar. Also check the dependencies.

Comment: Yes. I did both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add appcompat v7 dependencies to  the app gradle file.
Ensure build.gradle(Module : app) is having the dependency.
If not available then add and sync the project
It should be like-

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add android.support.v7.jar in the libs folder.Remove it and re sync. Post the Error Message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
I don't know why but when I changed the theme by this [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747943/how-to-change-actionbar-color)  the issue is up.