# How to change the color of the actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've been trying to change the actionbar's color without any succes. I've been searching for a while now...
I tried the solution of this post:
[How to change ActionBar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747943/how-to-change-actionbar-color)

This is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#0091ea</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: [Ckeck my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us/27847656#27847656)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by this way

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:background">YOUR_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarTextColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">YOUR_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
```

Obivously, you **have to** add this theme on your Activity in your AndroidManifest.

**EDIT**

Add those imports on your Activity

```
 import android.app.ActionBar;
 import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
```

Just below on yout onCreate put this

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
       ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#81a3d0"));     
       ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

> This works for me :
>
> getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff1d97dd));

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: When I try the first way my app stops working after I launch it.

I've tried the second way before I posted this topic, but somehow my actionbar does not change to the color I want

Comment: Did you add the theme on your Manifest? What is the error that are you facing with?

Comment: Thanks It works!
Although I don't think this is the proper way to change the color of the actionbar.
But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Android Asset Studio](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to create a custom ActionBar style, and therefore choose what color you want your AB to have.

You could also try the solution from this StackOverflow post [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Quote:

> Just in case, if you target for minimum API level 11 , you can change
>   ActionBar's background color by defining custom style, as:
>
> ```
> <resources>
>     <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
>         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
>         <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
>     </style>
> </resources>
> ```
>
> And, set "MyTheme" as theme for application / activity.

Answer (score 0):

> To change the action bar background, create a custom theme for your activity that overrides the actionBarStyle property. This property points to another style in which you can override the background property to specify a drawable resource for the action bar background.
>
> When supporting Android 3.0 and higher only, you can define the action bar's background like this:

**res/values/themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

> Then apply your theme to your entire app or individual activities:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground)

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom colors in your `styles.xml`.

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then create a `colors.xml` file and set your colors there in hex format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#F44336</color>
    <color name="primaryDark">#D32F2F</color>
    <color name="accent">#448AFF</color>
</resources>
```

Go here to learn more: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette