# Setting the ActionBar background colour to other than colorPrimary in XML

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have found similar questions but the answers did not work. I do not want to change the `colorPrimary`.

The ActionBar is not a ToolBar, so it does not exist in the activity's layout XML. The following did not work, and the bakground was still set to `colorPrimary`.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>
</resources>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Why you do not want to change the colorPrimary. While you want to change the color throught your app?

Comment: did you try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249702/9287163

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747943/how-to-change-actionbar-color?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I want colorPrimary (which is very conspicuous) for something that needs user's attention such as the selected date of calendar. But the ActionBar is something that is always there and does not need to be conspicuous, so I want a dull colour for it. You may disagree on my reasoning, but that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can do

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#YOUR_COLOR")));
```